# Sheets selected in listbox2 and exporting them to a new workbook

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, userform

Hopefully somebody can help me.

I have 2 Listboxes in a userform (Listbox1 & Listbox2), in Listbox1 I get the names of all the visible sheets in the workbook. 
In Listbox2 will be the sheets I select in Listbox1, to copy to a new workbook.

The filling of Listbox1 works, the copying of the sheetnames to Listbox2 workt too.
I select the sheetnames in Listbox2, and then use the following code to copy the sheets to a new workbook.

```
For K = 0 To ListBox2.ListCount - 1
    If ListBox2.Selected(K) Then
        Worksheets(ListBox2.List(K, 0)).Copy
    End If
Next K
```

But I get a runtime error-9 "Subscript out of range error"

Question:
What goes wrong here ? 
How do I change the code so that all selected items/sheets in Listbox2 are nicely exported to a new workbook.

Thanks for all the help

Comment: Which line is giving you the error?

Comment: @Cyril given the unqualified `Worksheets` call is implicitly referring to `ActiveSheet`, and that `n` list items might be checked, and that parameterless `Worksheet.Copy` creates & activates a new workbook, I'd assume any 2nd iteration breaks on `Worksheets(...).Copy`, since the active workbook has changed between iterations.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon my apologies for the cryptic inquiry... i was digging towards if there was an error on use of the listbox (is this code in the UserForm or is this within a module), where qualifications would use Me or UserForm1.Listbox, etc.  For all i know this is accessed through the userform code (e.g., when command button is clicked) or could be from a function in a module.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Thank you for your help, however the code is giving me an compile error on this line `ws.Copy .Worksheets(After:=.Worksheets(.Worksheets.Count))`

Comment: Right, untested air-code. Hopefully fixed now.

Comment: all the buttons / listboxes are in a userform

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Thank you so much, the code works flawless. And also thanks for the explanation of what the code does, really helps

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> Worksheets(ListBox2.List(K, 0)).Copy
> ```

Doing too many things at once, making too many assumptions: it's assuming that `ActiveWorkbook` has a worksheet that's named after `ListBox2.List(K, 0)`. It's also assuming that `ListBox2.List(K, 0)` will succeed.

Break it down.

```
Dim sheetName As String
sheetName = ListBox2.List(K, 0)
```

If this succeeds, we can proceed to get the worksheet:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetName)
```

If this succeeds, we can proceed to copy the sheet:

```
ws.Copy
```

But we're in a loop... and `ws.Copy` is going to change the `ActiveWorkbook` - so if the first iteration worked, the second is guaranteed to blow up.

The first thing to do is therefore to capture the "source" workbook before we even begin:

```
Dim srcBook As Workbook
Set srcBook = ActiveWorkbook
```

And then to use that object reference to qualify the `Worksheets` call:

```
...
Set ws = srcBook.Worksheets(sheetName)
...
```

Now, the next problem is, every selected sheet will be copied to a new workbook - meaning, every selected sheet gets *its own* new workbook.

If that's intended, all is good. But that's not how I read "*copy the sheets to a new workbook*" - right?

In order for all copies to end up in the same destination workbook, you need to keep a reference to that workbook. And since it's going to be created and activated on the fly by the first copy you make, I'd do something like this:

```
Dim dstBook As Workbook
...
If dstBook Is Nothing Then
'destination workbook doesn't exist yet
    ws.Copy
    Set dstBook = ActiveWorkbook
Else
'copy worksheet to destination workbook, after the last sheet
    With dstBook
        ws.Copy After:=.Worksheets(.Worksheets.Count)
    End With
End If
...
```

So:

```
Dim srcBook As Workbook
Set srcBook = ActiveWorkbook ' ThisWorkbook?

Dim dstBook As Workbook
For K = 0 To ListBox2.ListCount - 1
    If ListBox2.Selected(K) Then

        Dim sheetName As String
        sheetName = ListBox2.List(K, 0)

        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Set ws = srcBook.Worksheets(sheetName)

        If dstBook Is Nothing Then
        'destination workbook doesn't exist yet
            ws.Copy ' creates & activates a new workbook
            Set dstBook = ActiveWorkbook 'there's our destination
        Else
        'copy worksheet to destination workbook, after the last sheet
            With dstBook
                ws.Copy After:=.Worksheets(.Worksheets.Count)
            End With
        End If

    End If

Next
```

Comment: I have a extra question for the code that was used. Would it also be possible to copy the selected sheets as values only. So that all the formula's and links are removed.

Comment: @Erik not in the same step. `Worksheet.Copy` copies the sheet; dealing with formulas/values is the job of `Range.Copy`.

Comment: thanks, will have to dive into that to make that happen

Comment: @Erik `Range.PasteSpecial` with `xlValues` would do it, But I'd probably go with `theSheet.UsedRange.Value = theSheet.UsedRange.Value` (copies the values into a 2D array, then dumps that 2D array onto the source range, overwriting whatever formula provided the values).